# Why .collect() operator in swift Combine always sends .unlimited demand regardless of the demand of upstream publisher?

Tags: swift, combine

I have been playing with Combine to understand how it works in more details and I create a custom  Publisher, Subscription and Subscriber.

Here's how it looks..

The emoji beamer publisher along with subscription:

```
struct EmojiBeamerPublisher: Publisher {
    typealias Output = String
    typealias Failure = Error
    private let emojis: [String] = ["","❤️","✅","","","","","","","","❄️","","","","","✍️","","‍","","","","","","",""]
    
    func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S : Subscriber, Self.Failure == S.Failure, Self.Output == S.Input {
        let subscription = EmojiBeamerSubscription(output: emojis, subscriber: subscriber)
        subscriber.receive(subscription: subscription)
    }
}

extension EmojiBeamerPublisher {
    private final class EmojiBeamerSubscription<S: Subscriber>: Subscription where S.Input == Output, S.Failure == Failure {
        var subscriber: S?
        let output: [String]
        init(output: [String], subscriber: S) {
            self.subscriber = subscriber
            self.output = output
        }
        
        func request(_ demand: Subscribers.Demand) {
            Swift.print("Demand: \(demand)") // Here I receive Unlimited demand
            var demand = demand
            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: true) { [weak self] timer in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                guard demand > 0, let subscriber = self.subscriber else {
                    timer.invalidate()
                    self.subscriber?.receive(completion: .finished)
                    self.cancel()
                    return
                }
                demand -= 1
                demand += subscriber.receive(self.output.randomElement()! + " \(Date())")
            }
        }
        
        func cancel() {
            subscriber = nil
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Custom subscriber:

```
final class EmojiBeamerSubscriber<Input, Failure: Error>: Subscriber, Cancellable {
    var subscription: Subscription?
    let receiveValue: (Input) -> Void
    
    init(receiveValue: @escaping (Input) -> Void) {
        self.receiveValue = receiveValue
    }
    
    func receive(subscription: Subscription) {
        self.subscription = subscription
        subscription.request(.max(3)) // Here I send only 3 as max demand
    }
    
    func receive(_ input: Input) -> Subscribers.Demand {
        receiveValue(input)
        return .none
    }
    
    func receive(completion: Subscribers.Completion<Failure>) {
        print("Will handle later:", completion)
    }
    
    func cancel() {
        self.subscription?.cancel()
        self.subscription = nil
    }
}

extension Publisher {
    func myCustomSink(receiveValueHandler: @escaping (Self.Output) -> Void) -> AnyCancellable {
        let myCustomSubscriber = EmojiBeamerSubscriber<Self.Output, Self.Failure>(receiveValue: receiveValueHandler)
        subscribe(myCustomSubscriber)
        return AnyCancellable(myCustomSubscriber)
    }
}
```

As you can see on my custom subscription I request with demand `.max(3)` if I don't use collect everything works fine, I get an emoji beamed every 5 second after 3 I got a `.finish` completion.

Works fine (and sends .max(3) demand):

```
let emojiBeamer = EmojiBeamerPublisher()
var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

emojiBeamer
    .myCustomSink { value in Swift.print("Random Emoji:: \(value)") }
    .store(in: &cancellables)
```

However if I simply add `.collect()` to catch all 3 results at once in an array it just requests with `.unlimited` demand on my subscription, resulting in a never ending subscription because my demand will never reach `zero`.

Never complete (and sends unlimited demand):

```
let emojiBeamer = EmojiBeamerPublisher()
var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

emojiBeamer
    .collect()
    .myCustomSink { value in Swift.print("Random Emoji:: \(value)") }
    .store(in: &cancellables)
```

Is there something wrong with my implementation? Or Did I misunderstood the purpose of `.collect()` operator?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/merge/collect()):

> This publisher requests an unlimited number of elements from the upstream publisher and uses an unbounded amount of memory to store the received values. The publisher may exert memory pressure on the system for very large sets of elements.

So the behaviour you noticed is the correct one, as `collect()` sends an unlimited demand upstream.

The `unlimited` demand causes the `demand -= 1` instruction to do nothing, so the `demand > 0` check will always pass, resulting into an infinite loop that never sends the completion. You will need an extra condition to make the "collected" stream a finite one.

For infinite streams, the [collect(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/merge/collect(_:)) overload (the one that allows to pass a number of items to collect) performs better in regards to the demand, but still requests from upstream more elements than one might expect:

> When this publisher receives a request for .max(n) elements, it requests .max(count * n) from the upstream publisher.

Comment: Thank you for sharing that Cristik,

I didn't quite get the documentation page they also say that:

`Use collect() to gather elements into an array that the operator emits after the upstream publisher finishes.`

But the upstream will never finish if demand is infinite,

the little example they show on documentation page seems to work with .collect() that kind of publisher, 
I am likely missing something important on the implementation of my Custom Publisher/Subscription

the .collect(_:) allows it to end but in a weird fashion if I pass `1` it sends me 3 arrays with 1 element each.

Comment: @Lucas your `guard demand > 0` will always succeed, as the `demand -= 1` decrement will do nothing for an unlimited demand. Thus, as you noticed, the upstream will never finish. You need an extra condition there, like ending the stream after N elements, otherwise `collect()` will indefinitely wait. That's just how `collect()` works, for infinite streams you'll need to use `collect(N)`.